# How to use BitmapImage setting UriSource with a remote server?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I need to create a BitmaImage from a UriSrouce and print it (in a WPF app). Using the following code I am able to print the image:

```
Image imgVoucher = new Image();
BitmapImage bImgVoucher = new BitmapImage();

bImgVoucher.BeginInit();
bImgVoucher.UriSource = new Uri(@"C:\logo-1.png", UriKind.Absolute); // Print ok
bImgVoucher.EndInit();
imgVoucher.Source = bImgVoucher;
```

Same code and same image but with UriSource pointing to a web server, the image is not printed and no error is thrown. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

```
Image imgVoucher = new Image();
BitmapImage bImgVoucher = new BitmapImage();

bImgVoucher.BeginInit();
bImgVoucher.UriSource = new Uri("http://123123.com/logo.png", UriKind.Absolute); // Does not print
bImgVoucher.EndInit();
imgVoucher.Source = bImgVoucher;
```

Comment: I can load the picture in my browser

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The image might not be downloaded completely. Before printing, check the `IsDownloading` property and add a `DownloadCompleted` event handler if needed:

```
var bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://123123.com/logo.png"));

if (!bitmap.IsDownloading)
{
    // print immediately
}
else
{
    bitmap.DownloadCompleted += (o, e) =>
    {
        // print when download completed
    };
}
```

---

An alternative (synchronous) solution would be to download the complete image data before creating a BitmapImage, e.g. like this:

```
var buffer = new WebClient().DownloadData("http://123123.com/logo.png");
var bitmap = new BitmapImage();

using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
{
    bitmap.BeginInit();
    bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmap.StreamSource = stream;
    bitmap.EndInit();
}

// print now
```

Comment: could be a solution setup Synchronously download? thanks for your answer